# curl prints its pid then runs in background

Tags: files, curl, download

I'm experiencing something new with a simple `curl` request.

The command is a plain call of curl such as this:

`curl http://example.com/endpoint/?arg1=val1&arg2=val2`

The call is supposed to return a 500+ MB XML file (when ready, I will just `-O` it to save to a file), but there is nothing strange, really.

What is strange is that curl just print it's pid and the goes into background:

`[1] 31562`

After a while, the remote file starts to appear into the console and, being in background, I cannot kill it with `Ctrl+C`.

I never experienced something like this. If I try to download 1.9 GB file:

`curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/A/F/0AFB5316-3062-494A-AB78-7FB0D4461357/7601.17514.101119-1850_Update_Sp_Wave1-GRMSP1.1_DVD.iso`

It works normally!

Any idea?

Headers from a regular download:

```
curl -v -s https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/A/F/0AFB5316-3062-494A-AB78-7FB0D4461357/7601.17514.101119-1850_Update_Sp_Wave1-GRMSP1.1_DVD.iso 1> /dev/null
*   Trying 92.123.112.141:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to download.microsoft.com (92.123.112.141) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
... more HTTPS stuff ...
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /download/0/A/F/0AFB5316-3062-494A-AB78-7FB0D4461357/7601.17514.101119-1850_Update_Sp_Wave1-GRMSP1.1_DVD.iso HTTP/1.1
> Host: download.microsoft.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
< x-ms-blob-content-md5: mw6jWIuMir1+rZG9/mzj+A==
< Last-Modified: Sat, 13 Oct 2018 00:34:54 GMT
< ETag: "0x8D630A3B1CF6138"
< Content-Length: 2048196608
< Date: Mon, 10 Feb 2020 21:11:55 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
{ [16038 bytes data]
^C
```

My call:

```
*   Trying 192.168.0.200:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com port 80 (#0)
> GET /endpoint/?arg1=val1&arg2=val2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
> 
^C
```

Comment: It's not that new.  (-:  People have been experiencing this for years.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/280645/5132 is just one example.

Comment: It was for me. In the past I used to put quotes around everything. These days not so much :-(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That URL contains an unquoted `&` character. This means that your command would start

```
curl http://example.com/endpoint/?arg1=val1
```

in the background, and then set the shell variable `arg2` to the value `val2`, since that's what the next bit of the URL means when the shell parses the line.

Use quotes around the URL:

```
curl 'http://example.com/endpoint/?arg1=val1&arg2=val2'
```

---

Even if the URL hadn't contained a `&`, the `?` character is a globbing character  (matches any single character in a filename globbing pattern).  Leaving the URL unquoted would therefore cause the `zsh` shell with its default settings to complain about `no matches found`. It would also cause the `bash` shell to complain with `no match` if its `failglob` shell option was set. Likewise, the URL would be deleted completely if any shell was configured to remove patterns with no matches (as with `shopt -s nullglob` in `bash`).

---

Bonus:

I would probably write that `curl` command as

```bash
curl --silent \
    --url-query arg1=val1 \
    --url-query arg2=val2 \
    'http://example.com/endpoint/'
```

Using `--url-query` would make `curl` URL-encode the data, and also lets you load data from a file (see the option in the `curl` manual, and also see the description of `--data-urlencode` therein as it chares the semantics).  It also avoids injecting the values of shell variables directly into the URL string (if the values had been values taken from shell variables).

See also `--variable` which could also be useful to know about.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace & with %2, encode the url

This will work -
curl 'http://example.com/endpoint/?arg1=val1%2arg2=val2'

It's best always use curl with encoded url - https://www.urlencoder.org/

Comment: This is wrong; it transmits a single parameter arg1 with value `val1*rg2=val2` (because %2a or %2A is asterisk; if the intended second parameter hadn't begun with a-f or A-F it would be invalid) whereas the original _if correctly quoted_ transmits _two_ parameters: arg1 containing `val1` _and separately_ arg2 containing `val2`.